# N1QL nested json, query on field inside object inside array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have json documents in my Couchbase cluster that looks like this

```
 {
    "giata_properties": {
      "propertyCodes": {
        "provider": [
          {
            "code": [
              {
                "value": [
                  {
                    "name": "Country Code",
                    "value": "EG"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "City Code",
                    "value": "HRG"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Hotel Code",
                    "value": "91U"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "providerCode": "gta",
            "providerType": "gds"
          },
          {
            "code": [
              {
                "value": [
                  {
                    "value": "071801"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": [
                  {
                    "value": "766344"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "providerCode": "restel",
            "providerType": "gds"
          },
          {
            "code": [
              {
                "value": [
                  {
                    "value": "HRG03Z"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": [
                  {
                    "value": "HRG04Z"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "providerCode": "5VF",
            "providerType": "tourOperator"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to create a query that fetches a single document based on the value of `giata_properties.propertyCodes.provider.code.value.value` and a specific `providerType`.

So for example, my input is `071801` and `restel`, I want a query that will fetch me the document I pasted above (because it contains these values).

I'm pretty new to N1QL so what I tried so far is (without the providerType input)

```
SELECT * FROM giata_properties AS gp 
WHERE ANY `field` IN `gp.propertyCodes.provider.code.value` SATISFIES `field.value` = '071801' END;
```

This returns me an empty result set. I'm probably doing all of this wrongly.

**edit1:**

According to geraldss answer I was able to achieve my goal via 2 different queries

1st (More general) `~2m50.9903732s`

```
SELECT * FROM giata_properties AS gp WHERE ANY v WITHIN gp SATISFIES v.`value` = '071801' END;
```

2nd (More specific) `~2m31.3660388s`

```
SELECT * FROM giata_properties AS gp WHERE ANY v WITHIN gp.propertyCodes.provider[*].code SATISFIES v.`value` = '071801' END;
```

Bucket have around 550K documents. No indexes but the primary currently.

**Question part 2**

When I do either of the above queries, I get a result streamed to my shell very quickly, then I spend the rest of the query time waiting for the engine to finish iterating over all documents. I'm sure that I'll be only getting 1 result from future queries so I thought I can use LIMIT 1 so the engine stops searching on first result, I tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM giata_properties AS gp WHERE ANY v WITHIN gp SATISFIES v.`value` = '071801' END LIMIT 1;
```

But that made no difference, I get a document written to my shell and then keep waiting until the query finishes completely. How can this be configured correctly?

**edit2:**

I've upgraded to the latest enterprise `4.5.1-2844`, I have only the primary index created on `giata_properties` bucket, when I execute the query along with the LIMIT 1 keyword it still takes the same time, it doesn't stop quicker.

I've also tried creating the array index you suggested but the query is not using the index and it keeps insisting on using the `#primary` index (even if I use USE INDEX clause).

I tried removing SELF from the index you suggested and it took a much longer time to build and now the query can use this new index, but I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing here.

So 3 questions:

1) Why LIMIT 1 using primary index doesn't make the query stop at first result?

2) What's the difference between the index you suggested with and without SELF? I tried to look for `SELF` keyword documentation but I couldn't find anything.

This is how both indexes look in Web ui

*Index 1 (Your original suggestion)* - Not working

```
CREATE INDEX `gp_idx1` ON `giata_properties`((distinct (array (`v`.`value`) for `v` within (array_star((((self.`giata_properties`).`propertyCodes`).`provider`)).`code`) end)))
```

*Index 2 (Without `SELF`)*

```
CREATE INDEX `gp_idx2` ON `giata_properties`((distinct (array (`v`.`value`) for `v` within (array_star(((self.`propertyCodes`).`provider`)).`code`) end)))
```

3) What would be the query for a specific `giata_properties.propertyCodes.provider.code.value.value` and a specific `providerCode`? I managed to do both separately but I wasn't successful in merging them.

Thanks for all your help dear

Comment: Does your document actually contain the giata_properties field?

Comment: @geraldss No, sorry. Here is a real sample of the documents I have in the `giata_properties` bucket http://pastebin.com/mbXFMPkA

Comment: Ok, that would explain any mismatches in the solution, @pretty.

Comment: @geraldss My bad. Could you please answer my 3 questions above? I really need a query (and an index) that fetches a document based on `value` and `providerCode`.

Comment: Can you post a new clean question. I'll answer.

Comment: I'm sorry this got messy I know. New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071965/couchbase-n1ql-array-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a query without the `providerType`.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM giata_properties AS gp
WHERE ANY v WITHIN gp.giata_properties.propertyCodes.provider[*].code SATISFIES v.`value` = '071801' END;
```

You can also index this in Couchbase 4.5.0 and above.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON giata_properties( DISTINCT ARRAY v.`value` FOR v WITHIN SELF.giata_properties.propertyCodes.provider[*].code END );
```

**Edit to answer question edits**

The performance has been addressed in 4.5.x. You should try the following on Couchbase 4.5.1 and post the execution times here.

- Test on 4.5.1.
- Create the index.
- Use the LIMIT. In 4.5.1, the limit is pushed down to the index.

Comment: Thanks geraldss, that works and it's really nice that you don't have to specify which `value` field you're referring to in N1QL (does that impact performance by the way?). But can you clarify exactly how can I specify in N1QL which field it should be looking at? For example I want my query to only look at `gp.propertyCodes.provider.code.value.value` and not all fields with the name `value`. Also can I do the index you suggested on the community edition 4.1.0?

Comment: Array indexing is only available in 4.5 and above. I will edit the answer to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I wonder if this more specific query have better performance than the earlier more general one, I'll do benchmarks soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Posted some benchmarks and an update to my question, help would be very much appreciated.