# Couchbase N1QL array query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Document sample from my `giata_properties` bucket: [link](http://pastebin.com/mbXFMPkA)

Relevant json paste

```
{
  "propertyCodes": {
    "provider": [
      {
        "code": [
          {
            "value": [
              {
                "value": "304387"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "providerCode": "hotelbeds",
        "providerType": "gds"
      },
      {
        "code": [
          {
            "value": [
              {
                "name": "Country Code",
                "value": "EG"
              },
              {
                "name": "City Code",
                "value": "HRG"
              },
              {
                "name": "Hotel Code",
                "value": "91U"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "providerCode": "gta",
        "providerType": "gds"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "Arabia Azur Resort"
}
```

I want a query (and an index) to retrieve a document based on `propertyCodes.provider.code.value.value` and `propertyCodes.provider.providerCode`. I've managed to do each separately but I'm not sure how to merge both of them in a single query.

```
SELECT meta().id FROM giata_properties AS gp USE INDEX(`#primary`) WHERE ANY v WITHIN gp.propertyCodes.provider[*].code SATISFIES v.`value` = '150613' END;

SELECT meta().id FROM giata_properties AS gp USE INDEX(`#primary`) WHERE ANY v within gp.propertyCodes.provider[*].providerCode SATISFIES v = 'hotelbeds' END;
```

So for example I want to fetch the document that includes `propertyCodes.provider.code.value.value` of `304387` and that `provider` is also `hotelbeds`, because code value can be duplicated over documents, but code and providerCode combination is unique.

Comment: Looking at the link. Please add the relevant sections of a single document to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the query and the indexes.

The query.

```
SELECT META().id
FROM giata_properties AS gp
WHERE ANY p IN propertyCodes.provider SATISFIES ( ANY v WITHIN p.code SATISFIES v.`value` = '304387' END ) AND p.providerCode = 'hotelbeds' END;
```

The indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_value ON giata_properties
( DISTINCT ARRAY ( DISTINCT ARRAY v.`value` FOR v WITHIN p.code END ) FOR p IN propertyCodes.provider END );

CREATE INDEX idx_providerCode ON giata_properties
( DISTINCT ARRAY p.providerCode FOR p IN propertyCodes.provider END );
```

Comment: Thanks, the query and the index works great. Curious about one thing, created `idx_value` and then `EXPLAIN` showed the query's using `idx_value` alone and it was pretty fast, then I created `idx_providerCode` and `EXPLAIN` showed the query is now using both indices. No performance improvement was measured between the query using both indices and a single index, could you please explain a bit? Explain output http://pastebin.com/V1mk16iW

Comment: Well, IntersectScan is not free. Also, if the indexes are on the same node, they are sharing resources (CPU, memory), so there may not be speedup.

Comment: My question then, in my case, can I create a single composite index to avoid `IntersectScan` and stick to `IndexScan` maybe?

Comment: Also if my query works by using index `idx_value` alone, why do I need both indices?

Comment: You need two indexes in general. If your idx_value is more selective than idx_providerCode, then stick with idx_value alone. It all depends on your data distribution.